# How to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 without internet without internet connection?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upgrade from 10.04 or 11.10 to 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

I want to upgrade from ubuntu 11.10 to ubuntu 12.04. But my internet connection is not fast enough to do the task well. Is there any other way to upgrade my distro/ or anything that i can download to upgrade my distro. offline ?

Comment: Either you have buy it or download. Or if you are in India, you can buy a Linuxforyou magazine. Check this month' edition probably they get on or the other versions of Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

1. Download 12.04 ISO from any other fast Internet source and then
2. Make it as a Live CD/USB then boot from it
3. Start installation and select the *Upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04* option in the installation process

[image: select the ticked mark option]

Comment: As one might want to add: You can also buy a copy of Ubuntu on CD, if not fast internet connection is to be found.