# Can I split the upgrade downloads into multiple parts?

Tags: upgrade

I'm using internet through mobile phone, can I upgrade ubuntu the latest version by 2 or 3 parts? because connection is very slow.  my current version ubuntu 10.10.

How can I split the downloads into multiple parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to download the iso and use it as a live cd/usb drive.

See here: [How to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 without internet without internet connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148920/how-to-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04-without-internet-without-internet-connection)

Comment: A torrent could be useful...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to incremental update from 10.10 to 11.10 first.  This, unfortunately, means you'll need multiple ISOs.  First, the 11.04 ISO.  Then, the 11.10 iso.  Then, the 12.04 ISO.  You'll need to get the relevant ISOs, though, you didnt specify any specific architecture for your system.

11.04 ISO: http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/

11.10 ISO: http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/

12.04 ISO: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

Then, using each of those, you should be able to follow the guide that [To Do linked to](https://askubuntu.com/a/173383/10616)

Comment: I think that the question is to split the downloads in parts, not something version-related.

Comment: That's not how I"m interpreting the question.  He hasnt asked how to segregate the downloads.  he's asked how to upgrade the version in parts.

Comment: yes! I want to split the downloads in 2 or 3 parts

Comment: @sasi please be more precise next time, then, when writing your questions, otherwise vague questions are open to massive interpretation. I've edited your question and title accordingly.  Note you'll still need to do the incremental upgrades method, there's no way to upgrade from 10.10 to 12.04 directly (if that is your goal)

Comment: Sorry! the little confusions...Thanks a lot! for your

Comment: again, thanks a lot! for your valuable answers...