# Can I apply all updates by downloading and clicking a .deb?

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Can updates be found in a standalone .deb format? I want something just like the Service Packs in Windows, which can be easily downloadable version-wise from anywhere without using any script and can be applied simply by double clicking.

Answer (score 4):

1. I'm not 100% sure, but I think you can use the **alternate cd installer** to update your ubuntu from i.e. 12.04 to 12.04.1: http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

   You may use the cd as a "deb package cd repository" -- once you burn it and insert in the CD driver, it will be picked up.
2. The normal **desktop cd** has an option to **upgrade** from older versions. It doesn't touch your personal files, only system files and packages. Also, it doesn't keep the settings you specified in /etc/: https://askubuntu.com/a/148923/5538
3. Try the **keryx** project: http://keryxproject.org/

   > Keryx is a free and open source tool for easily managing packages on
   >   offline Debian based computers including support for Ubuntu and Linux
   >   Mint.

   [Downloads](https://launchpad.net/keryx/+download), [Wiki](http://keryxproject.org/wiki/doku.php), [Forums](http://keryxproject.org/forums/).
4. Try using the **Synaptic package manager**: http://techspalace.blogspot.com/2009/04/offline-update-ubuntu.html

   Steps:

   - **Download/install** Synaptic Package Manager
   - Select the packages you want to install. Do not apply the update!
   - Go to File and select Generate Package Download Script
   - Save the file and bring it to the computer that has Internet.
   - Run that file.
   - It will download all the packages and its dependencies.
   - Put them in a removable drive.
   - Bring the drive back to the old machine.
   - Open Synaptic Package Manger again.
   - From File menu choose Add Downloaded Packages.
5. You may also want to try http://apt-offline.alioth.debian.org/ -- install **apt-offline-gui** or apt-offline package

   [Screenshots](http://screenshots.debian.net/package/apt-offline-gui)

Answer (score 1):

In short No.

Equivalent service pack of ubuntu 12.04 LTS (version 12.04.1) can be found in ISO format once the release point is reached.

Or you can use upgrade/update manager to download all updates.

If you want it for an offline computer you can go with ISO option or [see here](https://askubuntu.com/a/72270/35775)

Comment: Yes, many ways exist but still windows ways of offline update is much faster and easy. Can developer be requested to develop ubuntu update just like windows service pack ?

Comment: The amount of updates and packages that are changed with security fixes etc.. wouldn't make these feasible. You could use another online pc to upgrade your offline one check out the following information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Use_Offline_apt-get_update

Comment: Following #2 in medigeek's answer is "Service Packish" enough I think.