# How to update Ubuntu on a dual boot system without internet connection?

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, windows-7

I have windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.4 on my Lenovo G580. I want to upgrade my Ubuntu to 12.04 without removing windows is it possible?

Just to add WIFI/LAN do not work with Ubuntu 10.4 on my laptop due to driver issues.

How to do it?

Comment: Use Unetbootin to burn the Ubuntu 12.04 image to a USB pen. Boot from the pen and click on the install icon. Choose Upgrade Ubuntu, instead of Install and the other options.

In the mean time, you might want to follow the instructions from this Question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/205582/how-do-i-get-an-atheros-ar8162-working
It will provide you with drivers for your laptop's wireless card.

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/148920/62483

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the ubuntu 12.04 from the [Ubuntu web site.](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/)
2. Create a [bootable USB](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).
3. boot from the USB.
4. Choose "upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04" in the selection menu as shown in The answer you've linked.

Please comment if you need more instructions and if you have any questions, Good luck!

Comment: Can you please elaborate step 3. How to upgrade 10.04 after booting from USB. Thanks !

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148920/how-to-upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04-without-internet-without-internet-connection explains point no. 3 in detail thanks.

Comment: @nav_jan http://askubuntu.com/a/148923/10698 in the picture shown here (it's the installer window) choose upgrade. So, boot from the USB, choose install Ubuntu and then select upgrade in the menu instead. :)