# Ubuntu live CD upgrade option grayed out (13.10)

Tags: upgrade, system-installation

I currently have windows 7 and ubuntu 13.04 on the same HD. I would like to upgrade ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 without using the internet.

So I inserted the USB drive and it detects my windows 7  and my ubuntu 13.04 installation perfectly. But the first choice in the list which is:

"Upgrade Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10
Documents, music and other personal files will be kept. Installed software will be kept where possible. System wide settings will be cleared."

It is completely grayed out. But that is the option I would like to chose and I don't know why it is disabled.

What must I do to enable that option?

Else can I upgrade my installation by booting the live CD?

Comment: You mean that you are not able to *select* that specific option, right? Note: the LiveCD is same than LiveUSB, no differences.

Comment: I think the reason why upgrade is disabled is because I am not online. You must be connected to the net to upgrade.

Comment: AFAIK if your Live edition is Ubuntu 13.10, then it should not need anything else. I think that there is a question about it already, let me find..

Comment: If you use Windows, either you have already 4 partitions, Windows wasn't shutdown properly, the NTFS partition is dirty.

Comment: Yes, it should be fine. Here are those questions: [How to update Ubuntu on a dual boot system without internet connection?](http://askubuntu.com/a/308271/62483) & [How to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 without internet without internet connection?](http://askubuntu.com/q/148920/62483) & [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/110477/62483)

Comment: I made some tests, you need to have an internet connection in order for the "upgrade" option to be enabled. Else you can only reinstall from scratch. So I'll have to wait a few days until my bandwidth gets back.

Comment: @larienna That is great! I mean, you found the root of the problem. Would you like to write a new *answer*? You will be helping other users too. Thank for your response!

Answer (score 1):

you need to have an internet connection in order for the "upgrade" option to be enabled. Else you can only reinstall from scratch.

source and credit: comment from @larienna